# How can I prevent Mathematica from filling up memory and crashing my PC when I execute a faulty instruction?

Tags: memory, crash

Sometimes I make a silly mistake and run code that keeps on filling up the memory. Once that is filled, my OS starts page swapping, and there's pretty much nothing I can do except reboot the PC.

An example is initializing and filling an array that is too large, for instance by selecting prime numbers in a range that is far beyond my PC's capabilities.

Last time this happened, my entire PC became unresponsive, and I had to reboot. Then I realized my mistake, but it was too late.

Is there an option I can use in Mathematica where the program would automatically stop/warn me if I'm about to fill up the available memory?

---

Note: I am using Mathematica 11.1.

Comment: without knowing exactly what you have, you could try adding [MemoryConstrained](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MemoryConstrained.html) around the function/expression which is eating so much RAM?  **Run a command until a memory limit is exceeded:** This command is available since version 1.